# DirectX or Hyper-V In google cloud?

Tags: hyper-v, google-cloud-platform, rdp, windows-server-2016, google-compute-engine

Okay so basically i want to run some programs thath need Directx , a good alternative would be RemoteFX with Hyper-V but google cloud plataform dosnt support Hyper-V. And RDP dosnt support Directx. I do have any alternative for succesfully running those? Or its impossible?

I already try installing Hyper-V and i always get : "a hypervisor is already running or the host server isnt compatible with Hyper-V"

I also try using anydesk/teamviewer but i realize thaths pretty useless cause you just connect with them to the RDP session, once you close the sesion, its the same. And if you dont close, you are just getting in the RDP. Same issue.

I also try installing all type of drivers also the GRID of nvidia, but nothing worked. Im already desesperated , if someone can help me out. Would be insane.

Comment: "I do have any alternative for succesfully running those?" - yes, do not use a cloud. Those are rather special use cases, do not expect a run the mill standard virtualizatoin provider to support them.

Comment: I want to run them in gcloud. because of these im asking here. If i want to find any other alternative i wouldnt ask for it.

Comment: Yeah, except as I said (love repeating myself, seriously) you have fringe requirements and expect a mainstream provider to cater for them. Does. Not. Work. Clouds are cost optimized, not "hey, what arange feature can we support that 4 people may need". And they do not care what YOU want at all - they offer mass products.

Comment: AWS offers bare metal servers. But those are not really cloud servers. Anything in the cloud is either a VM or a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to running Hyper-V on GCP, this is referred to as 'nested virtualization' and while it is possible to run a nested hypervisor, Windows Hyper-V is not currently supported. For more details please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

However one cloud based alternative that is worth checking out is Amazon Workspaces as they have GPU enabled virtual desktop services.  More details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gpu-powered-amazon-graphics-workspaces/).

However whether they provide the features required by your specific application is something you will have to test.